# How to print two strings on the same line in c using printf

Tags: c, char, printf, scanf, conversion-specifier

I am trying to print the out put of name and phone. Keeps showing this two errors in terminal

> format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’

and

> format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’

my code:

```
int main(void)
{
    char name,phone;
    int age;


    printf("Kindly input your name, age and phone number");
    scanf("%s %s %d", &name, &phone, &age);
    printf("%s %s %d\n", name, phone, age);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use single-character variables? Hint: no.

Comment: *Never* use `scanf()` on user input without checking the return value...

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that in this call of `printf`

```
printf("%s %s %d\n", name, phone, age);
```

argument expressions `name` and `phone` having the type `char` are promoted to the type `int` and there is used the conversion specification `%s` designed to output strings instead of integers.

Instead of declaring these variables as having the scalar type `char` you need to declare them as having a character array type to be able to store strings.

And you should change the prompt

```
printf("Kindly input your name, age and phone number");
```

like

```
printf("Kindly input your name, phone number and age: ");
```

For example

```
char name[20], phone[20];
int age;


printf("Kindly input your name, phone number and age: ");
scanf("%19s %19s %d", name, phone, &age);
printf("%s %s %d\n", name, phone, age);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code is likely to fault .. Actually, you are storing an array of characters (string) into a single char memory location. You should rather do this:

```
/* Note the array definition `[]`.
 * Note that 32 is an arbitrary length, change it as per your needs.
 */
char name[32], phone[32];
```

Then, as an array is already a pointer to memory location, you can use it without the `&`.

```
scanf("%31s %31s %d", name, phone, &age);
```

EDIT: as suggested in comment, you can restrict the maximum input size. Knowing a string is NULL-terminated, in the example the maximum total string length becomes `31`.

Comment: `scanf("%s ...` is a bad as [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).  Better to use a _width_ `scanf("%31s ...`.